# Can this algorithm be considered polynomial?

Tags: computational-complexity

Let us assume that an optimization algorithm requires $\mathcal{O}(n^{\log1/\epsilon})$ flops to find a solution $\bar{X}$ such that 
$$\| \bar{X} - X^{\star}\| \leq \epsilon$$  where $\epsilon < 1$ and $X^{\star}$ is the true optimum point.

What kind of algorithm is this? Can it be considered polynomial?

Comment: It is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme.

Comment: @user3680510 I think it was a PTAS if there was no $\log$ in the power.

Comment: Nevertheless, this should be better then a Fully Polynomial Time Approximation Scheme, right?

Comment: @user3680510 Seems like your comment should be an answer? (I'm not vouching for its correctness, just its purpose.)

Comment: @Mostafa for the definition of PTAS this does not matter.

Comment: @CMarius no it is worse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a polynomial-time approximation scheme (see [Polynomial-time Approximation Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme)). This can be seen since when you fix $\epsilon$, the running time is polynomial in $n$. It is however no FPTAS, since this would require that its running time is in $O((n/\epsilon)^C)$  for some fixed constant $C$ (see [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51495/ptas-definition-vs-fptas)).